# How to include CSS3 Pie in my Drupal site?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to use rounded corners on my Drupal site. I came across CSS3 Pie and would like to try it out. But where exactly do I include the code that I download? In the modules folder?

http://css3pie.com/download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module for that:
http://drupal.org/project/css3pie

The instruction on the project page are better than what I could explain it as having to be done.

Comment: Thank you!

Sorry, another question...

Re: The module will create an extra CSS file and add it to Drupal css array in a preprocess. The CSS will be recreated every time you save the settings or recreated if needed when caches get flushed (only 7.x version)

Where do I find this css file so I can add my styles to it?

Comment: That file is built from what is entered in the configuration for the css3pie module. It doesn't contain styling, only selectors which should have the css3pie functionality added to them, so you would do your styling with css3 as normal in your theme, and add the necessary selectors to the configuration page (or in a hook, or the theme info file). The README.txt that comes with the css3pie module describes how to do it all. As a side note; check css3pie doc's for the gotcha's, pitfalls and limitations: http://css3pie.com/documentation/

Comment: Thank you @Phizes
I've since created another topic. Hope you get a chance to have a look and possibly comment... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/css3pie-styles-not-being-picked-up-in-ie-how-to-reference-the-path